# Ajax call failing in Django

Tags: ajax, django, jquery, django-csrf, csrf-protection

I have the following ajax call to update a particular field of a model

```
$("#updateLink").click(function(){
    var dec_text = $('#desc_text').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:"/users/update_desc/",
        data: {
        'val': dec_text,
        },
        success: function(){
            $(".display, .edit").toggle();
            $("#descText").html(dec_text);
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("Error");
        },
    });
    return false;
});
```

and my view is this

```
@csrf_exempt
def update_desc(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            desc_text = request.POST.get('val', False)
            if desc_text:
                profile = user.profile
                profile.desc = desc_text
                profile.save()

            return_message = "Sent mail"
            return HttpResponse(return_message,mimetype='application/javascript')
```

I am constantly getting an error message and I don't know how to solve this. I even used the `csrf_exempt` decorator to workaround if the problem was caused by a missing `csrf token` but still the problem persists.

Except one `ajax post` which in my `base` template all the ajax calls are failing. Can anybody please help to understand what is happening here. I can give some more details if required.

**Edit:**

I have added the a `js` file containing this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax in my base template, so it means it is present in all my templates. And I am using django 1.3 version.

Comment: I am expecting that you are still getting the csrf_token missing error. If so my answer is posted below else state the error after you are used csrf_exempt.

Comment: Actually I do not know how to get the error, as you can see I have just put an alert in my `error` callback which tells me that my ajax call failed but it does not tell me what the error was. How can I get the error?

Comment: Firstly, in your settings.py file DEBUG = True. This would not display your ajax errors but definitely others which are not catered.

Comment: Secondly, download FireBug. That is a very useful tool for debugging. In there you would have a console panel. Click on it and reload your page. This would show any scripts that failed. Go on the line and copy error or open it in another tab. This would take you to the crash page if so

Comment: Yes that I had already sent, before adding the solution that you have given below I was getting this
`[30/Dec/2011 13:27:36] "POST /users/update_desc/ HTTP/1.1" 500 94752`
Now I don't see a post call being made at all, so it means the below solution is not helping. Can you suggest something else. Why am I getting a 500, is something wrong with my `view`?

Comment: Try using console.log('Successful') in the success function I wrote below in answer. If Successful is printed in the console of firebug then your view is working alright. Else you would have to debug your view.

Comment: Thanks alot, I figured out why I was getting that error, there was some problem with my view. But is it necessary for me to use `csrfmiddlewaretoken: document.getElementsByName('csrfmiddlewaretoken')[0].value` because now it is working without that also

Comment: Are you still using the POST method? It shouldn't work using POST without the CSRF middleware token.

Comment: I am using the `POST` method, and I am not using the middleware however I have added the `ajaxSend` javascript that has been given in the documentation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, you are using POST and not sending a **csrf token**. Try explicitly sending the csrf token rather than using the decorator **csrf_exempt**.
One way of doing this is with what I have done in *data*. That is to fetch the csrf token (or from your own method) and pass it in your arguments.

```
$.ajax({
        url : url,
        type: "POST",
        data : {csrfmiddlewaretoken: document.getElementsByName('csrfmiddlewaretoken')[0].value},
        dataType : "json",
        success: function( data ){
            // do something
        }
    });
```

Comment: Now nothing is happening, I just see a # at the end of the url it means the `return false` was not executed in the event handler

Comment: Follow the steps enlisted in the comments above.